# Update multiple rows in the database on form submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a View that displays multiple rows from the database. I am using a `For Loop` to display them and passing as `IList`. I want to update the database with only the form fields that have changed.

When debugging I am not getting every row in the database/form fields. There are only 7 rows. I am getting the exception below. What am I doing wrong?

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Attaching an entity of type 'TeamWeb.Models.Current_Antenna' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.'

Model

```
public partial class Current_Antenna
{
    public System.Guid rfds_processing_id { get; set; }
    public int rfds_id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string sector { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> position { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> qty { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> team_last_updated { get; set; }
    public string team_updated_by { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Current(Guid? id, string sector)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    IList<Current_Antenna> current = db.Current_Antenna.ToList();
    current = current.Where(x => x.rfds_processing_id == id)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.sector == "A" ? 1 :
                                    x.sector == "B" ? 2 :
                                    x.sector == "C" ? 3 :
                                    x.sector == "D" ? 4 :
                                    x.sector == "E" ? 5 :
                                    x.sector == "F" ? 6 : 6)
                    .ThenBy(x => x.type == "ANTENNA MAKE - MODEL" ? 1 :
                          x.type == "Antenna RET Motor (QTY/MODEL)" ? 2 :
                          x.type == "SURGE ARRESTOR (QTY/MODEL)" ? 3 :
                          x.type == "DIPLEXER (QTY/MODEL)" ? 4 :
                          x.type == "DUPLEXER (QTY/MODEL)" ? 5 :
                          x.type == "Antenna RET CONTROL UNIT (QTY/MODEL)" ? 6 :
                          x.type == "TMA/LNA (QTY/MODEL)" ? 7 :
                          x.type == "CURRENT INJECTORS FOR TMA (QTY/MODEL)" ? 8 :
                          x.type == "PDU FOR TMAS (QTY/MODEL)" ? 9 :
                          x.type == "FILTER (QTY/MODEL)" ? 10 :
                          x.type == "SQUID (QTY/MODEL)" ? 11 :
                          x.type == "RRH - 700 band (QTY/MODEL)" ? 12 :
                          x.type == "RRH - 850 band (QTY/MODEL)" ? 13 :
                          x.type == "RRH - 1900 band (QTY/MODEL)" ? 14 :
                          x.type == "RRH - AWS band (QTY/MODEL)" ? 15 :
                          x.type == "RRH - WCS band (QTY/MODEL)" ? 16 :
                          x.type == "Additional RRH #1 - any band (QTY/MODEL)" ? 17 :
                          x.type == "Additional RRH #2 - any band (QTY/MODEL)" ? 18 :
                          x.type == "Additional Component 1 (QTY/MODEL)" ? 19 :
                          x.type == "Additional Component 2 (QTY/MODEL)" ? 20 :
                          x.type == "Additional Component 3 (QTY/MODEL)" ? 21 :
                          x.type == "DC TRUNK (QTY/MODEL)" ? 22 :
                          x.type == "DC BLOCK (QTY/MODEL)" ? 23 : 23)
                    .ThenBy(x => x.position == 1 ? 1 :
                          x.position == 2 ? 2 :
                          x.position == 3 ? 3 :
                          x.position == 4 ? 4 :
                          x.position == 5 ? 5 :
                          x.position == 6 ? 6 :
                          x.position == 7 ? 7 : 7)
                    .Select(x => new Current_Antenna
                    {
                        id = x.id,
                        rfds_id = x.rfds_id,
                        rfds_processing_id = x.rfds_processing_id,
                        sector = x.sector,
                        position = x.position,
                        type = x.type,
                        model = x.model,
                        qty = x.qty,
                        team_last_updated = x.team_last_updated,
                        team_updated_by = x.team_updated_by
                    }).ToList();

        return View(current);

    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    //public ActionResult Current(IList<Current_Antenna> current)
    public ActionResult Current([Bind(Include = "id,rfds_id,rfds_processing_id,sector,type,position,qty,model,team_last_updated,team_updated_by")] IList<Current_Antenna> current)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (Current_Antenna item in current)
            {
                db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }                             
        }
        return View(current);
    }
```

View

```
@model IList<TeamWeb.Models.Current_Antenna>

@using System.Data

@{
ViewBag.Title = "TEAM: Current Antennas";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container2">
    <h3 class="h3-text">CURRENT ANTENNAS</h3>


    @{
        dynamic idGuid = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
        Guid id = new Guid(idGuid);

        string urlSector = Request.QueryString["sector"];
        if (Model.Any())
        {
            if (urlSector == " ")
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.Select(x => x.sector).First())
                {
                    urlSector = item.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    <div class="nav">
        @Html.ActionLink("BACK TO REPORT", "Review", new { id = id })
    </div>
    <hr />
    <br />
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Current", "RFDS", FormMethod.Post, new { id = id, enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <table align="center" style="width:1400px;border-spacing:0;">
            <tr style="height:25px;">
                <td colspan="8" style="font-weight:700;text-align:center;">
                    <table align="center" style="width:1200px;border-spacing:0;">
                        <tr class="rev-tr">
                            @if (!Model.Any())
                            {
                                <td style="font-weight:700;text-align:center;color:#e30000;">
                                    THIS IS A NEW SITE. IT DOES NOT HAVE AN EXISTING ANTENNA CONFIGURATION.
                                </td>
                            }
                            @foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x => x.sector).Select(x => x.sector).Distinct())
                            {
                                if (urlSector == item)
                                {
                                    <td style="font-weight:700;text-align:center;color:#e30000;">
                                        SECTOR @item
                                    </td>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <td style="font-weight:700;text-align:center;text-decoration:underline;">
                                        <a href="@Url.Action("Current", new { id = id, sector = @item })" class="a-edit">SECTOR @item</a>
                                    </td>
                                }
                            }

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:25px;">
                <th style="font-size:13px;font-weight:700;border-bottom:.5px solid;width:12.5%;">
                </th>
                <th style="font-size:13px;font-weight:700;border-bottom:.5px solid;width:12.5%;">
                    Position 1
                </th>
                <th style="font-size:13px;font-weight:700;border-bottom:.5px solid;width:12.5%;">
                    Position 2
                </th>
                <th style="font-size:13px;font-weight:700;border-bottom:.5px solid;width:12.5%;">
                    Position 3
                </th>
                <th style="font-size:13px;font-weight:700;border-bottom:.5px solid;width:12.5%;">
                    Position 4
                </th>
                <th style="font-size:13px;font-weight:700;border-bottom:.5px solid;width:12.5%;">
                    Position 5
                </th>
                <th style="font-size:13px;font-weight:700;border-bottom:.5px solid;width:12.5%;">
                    Position 6
                </th>
                <th style="font-size:13px;font-weight:700;border-bottom:.5px solid;width:12.5%;">
                    Position 7
                </th>
            </tr>

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {

                if (Model[i].sector == urlSector)
                {

                    //if (i % 6 == 0)
                    //{

                        <tr style="height:55px;">
                            <td style="text-align:right;font-size:13px;font-weight:600;border-bottom:.5px solid;white-space:nowrap;">
                                @Model[i].type:&nbsp;<br />
                                Qty:&nbsp;
                            </td>

                            <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom:.5px solid;border-left:.5px solid #808080;">

                                @if (Model[i].qty > 0 && Model[i].model == "")
                                {
                                    Model[i].qty = 0;
                                }

                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].rfds_id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].rfds_processing_id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].sector)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].type)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].position)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].team_last_updated)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].team_updated_by)

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].model, new { style = "font-size:13px;width: 150px;text-align:center;" })<br />
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].qty, new { style = "font-size:13px;width: 40px;text-align:center;" })

                                @{i++;}
                            </td>

                            <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom:.5px solid;border-left:.5px solid #808080;">

                                @if (Model[i].qty > 0 && Model[i].model == "")
                                {
                                    Model[i].qty = 0;
                                }

                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].rfds_id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].rfds_processing_id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].sector)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].type)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].position)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].team_last_updated)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].team_updated_by)

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].model, new { style = "font-size:13px;width: 150px;text-align:center;" })<br />
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].qty, new { style = "font-size:13px;width: 40px;text-align:center;" })

                                @{i++;}
                            </td>

                            <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom:.5px solid;border-left:.5px solid #808080;">

                                @if (Model[i].qty > 0 && Model[i].model == "")
                                {
                                    Model[i].qty = 0;
                                }

                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].rfds_id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].rfds_processing_id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].sector)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].type)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].position)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].team_last_updated)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].team_updated_by)

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].model, new { style = "font-size:13px;width: 150px;text-align:center;" })<br />
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].qty, new { style = "font-size:13px;width: 40px;text-align:center;" })

                                @{i++;}
                            </td>

                            <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom:.5px solid;border-left:.5px solid #808080;">

                                @if (Model[i].qty > 0 && Model[i].model == "")
                                {
                                    Model[i].qty = 0;
                                }

                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].rfds_id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].rfds_processing_id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].sector)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].type)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].position)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].team_last_updated)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].team_updated_by)

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].model, new { style = "font-size:13px;width: 150px;text-align:center;" })<br />
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].qty, new { style = "font-size:13px;width: 40px;text-align:center;" })

                                @{i++;}
                            </td>

                            <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom:.5px solid;border-left:.5px solid #808080;">

                                @if (Model[i].qty > 0 && Model[i].model == "")
                                {
                                    Model[i].qty = 0;
                                }

                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].rfds_id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].rfds_processing_id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].sector)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].type)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].position)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].team_last_updated)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].team_updated_by)

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].model, new { style = "font-size:13px;width: 150px;text-align:center;" })<br />
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].qty, new { style = "font-size:13px;width: 40px;text-align:center;" })

                                @{i++;}
                            </td>

                            <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom:.5px solid;border-left:.5px solid #808080;">

                                @if (Model[i].qty > 0 && Model[i].model == "")
                                {
                                    Model[i].qty = 0;
                                }

                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].rfds_id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].rfds_processing_id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].sector)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].type)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].position)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].team_last_updated)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].team_updated_by)

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].model, new { style = "font-size:13px;width: 150px;text-align:center;" })<br />
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].qty, new { style = "font-size:13px;width: 40px;text-align:center;" })

                                @{i++;}
                            </td>

                            <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom:.5px solid;border-left:.5px solid #808080;">

                                @if (Model[i].qty > 0 && Model[i].model == "")
                                {
                                    Model[i].qty = 0;
                                }

                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].rfds_id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].rfds_processing_id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].sector)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].type)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].position)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].team_last_updated)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].team_updated_by)

                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].id)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].model, new { style = "font-size:13px;width: 150px;text-align:center;" })<br />
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].qty, new { style = "font-size:13px;width: 40px;text-align:center;" })


                            </td>

                        </tr>   
                    //}                             
                }
            }

            <tr>
                <td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="8" align="center">
                    @if (Model.Any())
                    {
                        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-default" />
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <div class="nav">
            @Html.ActionLink("BACK TO REPORT", "Review", new { id = id })
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    }

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (Current_Antenna item in current)
            {
                db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
```

Comment: I had to make some additional changes to the View but this code worked and my changes are being saved now. However it is taking a while to save once submitted. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: While this may answer the question, code only answers are generally regarded as lo-quality. Providing some more description and context on why will improve the quality of this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Everything seemed to be working fine. I ran multiple tests. Now when I make a change on the form I am now getting the following error on db.SaveChanges(); SqlException: Subquery returned more than 1 value.

Comment: Please disregard the previous comment. I had been playing with triggers in sql and it was throwing the exception.

Comment: Check this link please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134232/any-difference-between-calling-savechanges-inside-and-outside-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 0):

There is no need calling `SaveChanges()` inside a for loop. From your class `Current_Antenna`, `rfds_processing_id` is a Guid which means it might be the primary key, and based on `ActionResult Current(Guid? id, string sector)`, the same Guid is passed in.

*You can actually get the items that have changed from the db and update those ones*

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Current([Bind(Include = "id,rfds_id,rfds_processing_id,sector,type,position,qty,model,team_last_updated,team_updated_by")] IList<Current_Antenna> current)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Current_Antenna db_item = null
        foreach (Current_Antenna item in current)
        {
            db_item = db.FirstOrDefault(m => m.rfds_processing_id == item.rfds_processing_id);
            if(db_item != null)
                db.Entry(db.item).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();               
    }
    return View(current);
}
```

Comment: Actually, the id is the primary key, rfds_processing_id is the same for all items in an order. I will adjust accordingly and try it.