# I can't update/edit One to one relationship with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core

All **CRUD** operations are working except updating/editing. I am using **Pomelo** since I am using Mysql. For the issue am facing, am using the same create form to edit the data but it throws an exception when I try editing.

This is the exception:

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
>   An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'ICFERApp.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Duplicate entry '3' for key 'IX_Education_StudentId'
>
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Duplicate entry '3' for key 'IX_Education_StudentId'
>
> at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior
>   ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ResultSet.cs:line 43
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(ResultSet
>   resultSet) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 81
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ReadFirstResultSetAsync(IOBehavior
>   ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 307

These are my model classes:

```
public class Student
{
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Middle Name")]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Nationality")]
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Gender")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Religion")]
        public string Religion { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Medical Condition")]
        public string MedicalCondition { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Deceased")]
        public string Deceased { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Home Address")]
        public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Country Of Residence")]
        public string CountryOfResidence { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="City")]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Date Of Birth")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public virtual Parents Parents { get; set; }
        public virtual Education Education { get; set; }
}

public class Parents
{
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Religion Of Deceased Father")]
        public string ReligionOfDeceasedFather { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Religion Of Deceased Mother")]
        public string ReligionOfDeceasedMother { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Date Of Demise Father")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
        public DateTime DateOfDemiseOfFather { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Date Of Demise Mother")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
        public DateTime DateOfDemiseOfMother { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Names of Mother")]
        public string NamesOfMother { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Names of Father")]
        public string NamesOfFather { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Religion of Mother")]
        public string ReligionOfMother { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Marital Status of Mother")]
        public string MaritalStatusOfMother { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Occupation of Mother")]
        public string OccupationOfMother { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Monthly Income")]
        public double MonthlyIncome { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

        public long? StudentId { get; set; }
}

public class Education
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Education Level")]
    public string EducationLevel { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="School")]
    public string School { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Address of School")]
    public string AddressOfSchool { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Head Teacher")]
    public string HeadTeacher { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Telephone")]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public  virtual Student Student { get; set; }

    public long? StudentId { get; set; }
}
```

My question would be why can't I be able to update automatically with the Entity Framework Core?

These are the methods responsible for editing in my **Controller** class :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult New(Student student, string IsEditMode)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         ViewBag.IsEditMode = IsEditMode;
         return View(student);
     }

     try
     {
         if (IsEditMode.Equals("false"))
         {
              _studentRepository.Create(student);
         }
         else
         {
             _studentRepository.Edit(student);
         }

         return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
     }
}

public IActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    try
    {
        ViewBag.IsEditMode = "true";

        var student = _studentRepository.GetSingleStudent(id);

        return View("New", student);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Content("Could not find Pet");
    }
}
```

Then, in my `Repository` class, this is the **Edit** method:

```
public void Edit(Student student)
{
    _context.Students.Update(student);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I will be very grateful with help regarding this blocker. Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is my form which handles both Creating and Editing.

```
@model Student

<form asp-action="New" method="Post" asp-controller="Student">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>

    <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden"/>
    <input name="IsEditMode" id="IsEditMode" value="@ViewBag.IsEditMode" type="hidden"/>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="MiddleName"></label>
            <input asp-for="MiddleName" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="MiddleName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
            <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Nationality"></label>
            <input asp-for="Nationality" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Nationality" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Gender"></label>
            <input asp-for="Gender" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Gender" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Religion"></label>
            <input asp-for="Religion" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Religion" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="MedicalCondition"></label>
        <input asp-for="MedicalCondition" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="MedicalCondition" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Deceased"></label>
        <input asp-for="Deceased" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Deceased" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="HomeAddress"></label>
            <input asp-for="HomeAddress" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="HomeAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="CountryOfResidence"></label>
            <input asp-for="CountryOfResidence" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="CountryOfResidence" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="City"></label>
        <input asp-for="City" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="DateOfBirth"></label>
        <input asp-for="DateOfBirth" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="DateOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Parents.ReligionOfDeceasedFather"></label>
        <input asp-for="Parents.ReligionOfDeceasedFather" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Parents.ReligionOfDeceasedFather" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Parents.ReligionOfDeceasedMother"></label>
        <input asp-for="Parents.ReligionOfDeceasedMother" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Parents.ReligionOfDeceasedMother" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Parents.DateOfDemiseOfFather"></label>
            <input asp-for="Parents.DateOfDemiseOfFather" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Parents.DateOfDemiseOfFather" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Parents.DateOfDemiseOfMother"></label>
            <input asp-for="Parents.DateOfDemiseOfMother" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Parents.DateOfDemiseOfMother" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Parents.NamesOfMother"></label>
            <input asp-for="Parents.NamesOfMother" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Parents.NamesOfMother" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Parents.NamesOfFather"></label>
            <input asp-for="Parents.NamesOfFather" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Parents.NamesOfFather" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Parents.ReligionOfMother"></label>
            <input asp-for="Parents.ReligionOfMother" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Parents.ReligionOfMother" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Parents.MaritalStatusOfMother"></label>
            <input asp-for="Parents.MaritalStatusOfMother" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Parents.MaritalStatusOfMother" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Parents.OccupationOfMother"></label>
            <input asp-for="Parents.OccupationOfMother" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Parents.OccupationOfMother" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Parents.MonthlyIncome"></label>
            <input asp-for="Parents.MonthlyIncome" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Parents.MonthlyIncome" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Guardian.FirstName"></label>
        <input asp-for="Guardian.FirstName" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Guardian.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Guardian.MiddleName"></label>
        <input asp-for="Guardian.MiddleName" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Guardian.MiddleName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Guardian.LastName"></label>
        <input asp-for="Guardian.LastName" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Guardian.RelationshipToOrphan"></label>
        <input asp-for="Guardian.RelationshipToOrphan" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Guardian.RelationshipToOrphan" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Guardian.Occupation"></label>
        <input asp-for="Guardian.Occupation" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Guardian.Occupation" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Guardian.MonthlyIncome"></label>
        <input asp-for="Guardian.MonthlyIncome" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Guardian.MonthlyIncome" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Guardian.EmployersName"></label>
        <input asp-for="Guardian.EmployersName" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Guardian.EmployersName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Guardian.WorkAddress"></label>
        <input asp-for="Guardian.WorkAddress" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Guardian.WorkAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Guardian.MobileNo"></label>
        <input asp-for="Guardian.MobileNo" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Guardian.MobileNo" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Guardian.PhysicalLocation"></label>
        <input asp-for="Guardian.PhysicalLocation" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Guardian.PhysicalLocation" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Guardian.Comments"></label>
            <input asp-for="Guardian.Comments" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Guardian.Comments" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Education.EducationLevel"></label>
            <input asp-for="Education.EducationLevel" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Education.EducationLevel" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Education.School"></label>
        <input asp-for="Education.School" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Education.School" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Education.AddressOfSchool"></label>
        <input asp-for="Education.AddressOfSchool" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Education.AddressOfSchool" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Education.HeadTeacher"></label>
        <input asp-for="Education.HeadTeacher" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Education.HeadTeacher" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label asp-for="Education.Telephone"></label>
        <input asp-for="Education.Telephone" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Education.Telephone" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Siblings.NumberOfBrothers"></label>
            <input asp-for="Siblings.NumberOfBrothers" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Siblings.NumberOfBrothers" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Siblings.NumberOfSisters"></label>
            <input asp-for="Siblings.NumberOfSisters" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Siblings.NumberOfSisters" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input asp-for="FirstName" type="submit" value="Save Student" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: can you check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982875/how-to-update-employee-and-identity-user-with-one-to-one-zero-relation/55987634#55987634) see if it helps. Basically you need to get the existing one and change the values, also mark the entity state as `Modified` also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56812164/update-multiple-rows-in-the-database-on-form-submission/56813762#56813762)

Comment: Thanks @Bosco, your answer worked. But it only updates the Students model class, it doesn;t update other `one-to-one` relationship fields, what could be added to the code.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55692042/insert-users-id-into-multiple-tabels-using-mvc-identity/55696493#55696493) is an example of saving to two tables, for your case after saving the Student, you need the student Id to save the Parent and Education. The Student model here `public IActionResult New(Student student, string IsEditMode)`, does it have The parent and education details you which to save in the db?

Comment: @Bosco, I think it has because `Parent` and `Education` are already in the Student class, let me know if I answered your question well.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it didn't help me. I will be very grateful if I get a direct one.@Bosco

Comment: I meant the Edit form does it have the fields needed for adding Parent and Education?

Comment: @Bosco, I have attached the form on the question, checkout the bottom of the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can update all the tables

```
public void Edit(Student student)
{
    var existingStudent = _context.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == student.Id);
    if (existingStudent != null)
    {
        //do the update to the database             
        _context.Entry(existingStudent).CurrentValues.SetValues(student);
        _context.Entry(existingStudent).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

        //then update the parent this way
        //first get the particular parent for this student
        var parent = _context.Parents.FirstOrDefault(m => m.StudentId == existingStudent.Id);

        _context.Entry(parent).CurrentValues.SetValues(student.Parents);
        _context.Entry(parent).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

        //do the same for Educations
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, actually, I have implemented this answer, but when I add the updating lines of the other models, the application no longer updates anymore, even the `Students` model. Even if I leave 2 tables to update they don't work and I don;t see any error message in the terminal.

Comment: when you debug do you see data in `student`? if yes check for the parent and education data there as well.